# Laravel adds "!#" to the root URL when clicking a Link with #

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to make my AngularJS routes work with Laravel 5.4. But I have a problem.

In my Welcome.blade.php file I have these links :

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#/list">List </a></li>
      <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Whenever I click a link, the URL changes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#!#%2Flist` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#!#%2Fcontact`instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/list` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/contact`. And I can't use AngularJS routing using `$routeProvider` this way.

How can I fix it please? Thank you in advance

Comment: What *are* you using for routing, then? Laravel isn't doing this, your JS router is.

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh I see, when I deleted `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>` I don't have the problem. But I need this file to use `AngularJS` routing. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand now, this was a breaking change in AngularJS 1.6 : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8. They use `!#` instead of '#'.

Comment: Thanks! i didn't know about the breaking change.